# JS `this` on Function Invocation

Tags: javascript

Working through [Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja](http://www.manning.com/resig/), I'm looking at constructors with respect to the `this` keyword.

```
function Ninja() { 
   this.skulk = function() { return this; }
}
```

Example:

```
var ninja1 = new Ninja();

window.onload = function() {
    assert(ninja1.skulk() === ninja1,
        "the 1st ninja is skulking");
};
```

> Output: the 1st ninja is skulking

However, if I add `var windowNinja = Ninja()`, why am I seeing this JavaScript error in Chrome?

```
    assert(windowNinja.skulk() === window,
        "the window ninja is skulking");
```

> output: JavaScript error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'skulk' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ninja` doesn't return anything so if you dont initiate an instance of it with new it returns undefined  and that is stored in `windowNinja`. You can just call

```
Ninja();
assert(window.skulk() === window,
    "the window ninja is skulking");
```

So the `this` in `Ninja` is the global object(window) so you're assigning a method `skulk` to it. which returns the object that invoked it.

Alternately you can add a return to the function

```
function Ninja() { 
   this.skulk = function() { return this; }
   return  this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. To learn, I put a `console.log(windowNinja)` after `var windowNinka = Ninja()` and saw `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You left out new, var windowNinja = new Ninja();

Comment: The `assert` fails when I add `new`.

Comment: Hmm, windowNinja.skulk() === windowNinja?  I guess without the new skulk would have been added to window so window.skulk() === window would have worked.

Comment: yeah. Musa's answer demonstrates that. I tried `var window = new Ninja()`, but `assert(window.skulk() === window, ...)` showed a JS error that "global window object does not have a skulk method". Also, I'm guessing using `var window` is bad practice as **window** is a global object, right?

Comment: Yes it is a scope thing.  It looks like Chrome applied Ninja to some object then totally forgot about the window you had just made and accessed the global one for the assert.